# Executing shell command with pipe in perl

Tags: perl, shell

I want the output of the shell command captured in variable of a perl script, only the first section of the command before the pipe "|" is getting executed, and there is no error while executing the script

```
File.txt 
Error input.txt got an error while parsing 
Info  output.txt has no error while parsing 

my $var = `grep Error ./File.txt | awk '{print $2}'`;
print "Errored file $var";
```

Errored file Error input.txt got an error while parsing

I want just the input.txt which gets filtered by awk command but not happening. Please help

Answer (score 2):

The `$` in `$2` is interpolated by Perl, so the command that the shell receives looks like:

```
grep Error ./File.txt | awk '{print }'
```

(or something else if you have recently matched a regular expression with capture groups). The workaround is to escape the dollar sign:

```
my $var = `grep Error ./File.txt | awk '{print \$2}'`
```

Answer (score 2):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.

If you had, you'd have gotten the following warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value $2 in concatenation (.) or string at scratch.pl line 4.
```

This would've alerted you to the problem in your command, namely that the $2 variable is being interpolated instead of being treated like a literal.

There are three ways to avoid this.

1) You can do what `mob` suggested and just escape the $2

```
my $var = `grep Error ./File.txt | awk '{print \$2}'`
```

2) You can use the [`qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html) form of backticks with single quotes so that it doesn't interpolate, although that is less ideal because you are using single quotes inside your command:

```
my $var = qx'grep Error ./File.txt | awk \'{print $2}\''
```

3) You can just use a pure perl solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($var) = do {
    local @ARGV = 'File.txt';
    map {(split ' ')[1]} grep /Error/, <>;
};
```